# Call GameOverScreen GameOverScreen.Setup();

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am having trouble activating the Game over screen and I was just curois if there was a way to check A tag Like this `GameOverScreen.Setup(Check Object hit and if tag is Obstacle);`

here is my script and also I did not work with Void OnTriggerEnter()

```
public GameOverScreen GameOverScreen;

public void GameOver(){

        GameOverScreen.Setup();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of checking what object hit another is with `OnTriggerEnter`
or `OnCollisionEnter`, then you can use `CompareTag` to check what tag the object you hit has then call `GameOver` from there.

Comment: I already said OnTriggerEnter2D dident work but Oncollision did so thank you I am also learning the basics of programming best of luck